# How can I quit ediff immediately without having to type 'y'

Tags: ediff

When I quit ediff with <kbd>q</kbd> I get asked if I really want to quit. I'd rather it quit immediately. There is nothing obvious under [customization](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ediff.html#Customization). There is a solution [here](https://github.com/scfrazer/.emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/src/my-ediff.el) which seems to work by redefining the <kbd>q</kbd> key, but I'm not sure of the details of how the function works. What's the simplest way to get quit to really mean quit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can advise `ediff-quit` so it dynamically rebinds `y-or-n-p` to a function that returns `t`.

```el
(defun disable-y-or-n-p (orig-fun &rest args)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'y-or-n-p) (lambda (prompt) t)))
    (apply orig-fun args)))

(advice-add 'ediff-quit :around #'disable-y-or-n-p)
```

This is more robust to upstream changes than redefining `ediff-quit`.

Comment: If it would notify that if any differed buffer changed, it would be perfect.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately I think you do have to either rebind q or adjust the source of `ediff-quit`. As is apparent in the source of `ediff-quit` the prompt always happens.

```el
(defun ediff-quit (reverse-default-keep-variants)
  "Finish an Ediff session and exit Ediff.
Unselects the selected difference, if any, restores the read-only and modified
flags of the compared file buffers, kills Ediff buffers for this session
\(but not buffers A, B, C\).

If `ediff-keep-variants' is nil, the user will be asked whether the buffers
containing the variants should be removed \(if they haven't been modified\).
If it is t, they will be preserved unconditionally.  A prefix argument,
temporarily reverses the meaning of this variable."
  (interactive "P")
  (ediff-barf-if-not-control-buffer)
  (let ((ctl-buf (current-buffer))
    (ctl-frm (selected-frame))
    (minibuffer-auto-raise t))
    (if (y-or-n-p (format "Quit this Ediff session%s? "
              (if (ediff-buffer-live-p ediff-meta-buffer)
                  " & show containing session group" "")))
    (progn
      (message "")
      (set-buffer ctl-buf)
      (ediff-really-quit reverse-default-keep-variants))
      (select-frame ctl-frm)
      (raise-frame ctl-frm)
      (message ""))))
```

I would suggest redefining `ediff-quit` in your `.emacs` and submitting a patch to the source adding a customization variable.

Remember that the implementation source in emacs is always a few keystrokes away. Presuming the elisp sources are installed, type <kbd>C-h f</kbd>, enter the function name and follow the link to where it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following rebind of q in ediff. If any of the buffers are modified, it asks if they are to be saved, then it just quits. If no buffers are modified, it just quits.

```el
(add-hook 'ediff-startup-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd"q") 'my-ediff-quit)))

(defun my-ediff-quit ()
  "If any of the ediff buffers have been modified, ask if changes
should be saved. Then quit ediff normally, without asking for
confirmation"
  (interactive)
  (ediff-barf-if-not-control-buffer)
  (let* ((buf-a ediff-buffer-A)
         (buf-b ediff-buffer-B)
         (buf-c ediff-buffer-C)
         (ctl-buf (current-buffer))
         (modified (remove-if-not 'buffer-modified-p
                                  (list buf-a buf-b buf-c))))
    (let ((save (if modified (yes-or-no-p "Save changes?")nil)))
      (loop for buf in modified do
            (progn
              (set-buffer buf)
              (if save
                  (save-buffer)
                (set-buffer-modified-p nil))))
      (set-buffer ctl-buf)
      (ediff-really-quit nil))))
```